# Combine two range filters inside a bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

In my ES index, documents have two fields, `score_min` and `score_max`, which I am trying to boost in a bool query.

I want to boost all documents for which `score_min <= expected_score <= score_max` is true.

I know that I can put two `range` queries in the must clause, but that would mean that other documents would get overlooked.

Is there a way to do something like this

```
..
..
"should": [
    ...
    ...
    "some_query": {
        "and": [
            "range": {
                 "score_min": {
                      "lte": expected_score
                 },
            },
            "range": {
                "score_max": {
                     "gte": expected_score
                 }
             }
             "boost": 2
         ]
      }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `function_score` query.  One of the added benefits is that your `range` query can be written as a filter instead, and so take advantage of filter caching:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": { "some_field": "foo bar" }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "boost_factor": 1.2
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "range": { "score_min": { "lte": 10 }}},
                { "range": { "score_max": { "gte": 10 }}}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

All results matching the query are returned, but any results which additionally match the filter will have their score multiplied by `boost_factor`.